# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') Errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I get this error whenever I try to fetch data, I don't know why, it should show me posts but it gives me an error and a white page!

**This the error I get**

[image]

**This the `Posts.jsx` code**

```
import Post from "../post/Post";
import "./posts.css";

export default function Posts({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div className="posts">
      {posts.map((p) => (
        <Post post={p} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**This the `Home.jsx` code**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Header from "../../components/header/Header";
import React from 'react'
import "./home.css"
import Posts from "../../components/posts/Posts";
import Sidebar from "../../components/sidebar/Sidebar";
import axios from "axios"


export default function Home() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchPosts = async ()=>{
      const res = await axios.get("/posts")
      setPosts(res.data)
    }
    fetchPosts()
  }, [])
  return (
      <>

        <Header />
        <div className="home">
        <Posts />
        <Sidebar />
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I don't know why I get this error if anyone can help !

Comment: you are not passing data(posts) to the Posts component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing data(posts) to the Posts component.

```
<Posts posts={posts}/>
```

**For the safer side what you can do**

1. Add default value of posts
2. Add nullish coalescing operator

```
export default function Posts({ posts = [] }) {
  return (
    <div className="posts">
      {posts?.map((p) => (
        <Post post={p} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you brother, I just noticed that I didn't pass the data to the component :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import Post from "../post/Post";
import "./posts.css";

export default function Posts({ posts }) {
  return (
    <div className="posts">
      {posts && posts.map((p) => (
        <Post post={p} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The reason why you are getting this error because the post take some time to get load because it returns a promise so you must for that to resolve in order to render to post the best practice is define a variable loading and show spinner until it resolve